# Polish to infix notation

Tags: stack, infix-notation

Lets say we have an expression in prefix notation `or(1) and A B or(2) or(3) C D E` (where A, B, C, D, E are boolean values and `or` numbered for convenience) that we want to convert to an infix notation. In principle I have two ways to evaluate it:
(1) start  at `or(3) C D`, then `or(2)`, then `and`, then `or(1)`
(2) start at `and A B` then check `or(3)`, `or(2)`. Lastly check `or(1)`

(1) Evaluate starting from right most operator
(2) Evaluate starting from left most operator having all operands as it's direct neighbors.

Both evaluations yield `(A and B) or C or D or E`.

Which evaluation sequence is correct?
Will these two evaluations ever give different result for the same prefix record?

Comment: You can do them in any order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~pjj/cs212/fix.html recommends the first method.

You will get the same result regarding of the order, so it is up to you.